# Compare string ID to BSON::ObjectId

Tags: ruby, arrays, mongodb, mongoid

I have an array of made up of type `BSON::ObjectId` and I want it to compare against some IDs as strings.

```
if my_array_of_BSON_ObjectIds.include?(@my_id_as_a_string)
   # delete the item from the array
else
   # add the item to the array as a BSON::ObjectId
end
```

This is not working as the types are different, can I turn my string into a `BSON::ObjectId`? If so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `BSON::ObjectId(@my_id_as_a_string)` for representation your id as `BSON::ObjectId`

refs http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/BSON.html#ObjectId-class_method

Answer (score 14):

Mongoid 2.x with 10gen's driver:

```
BSON::ObjectId.new('506144650ed4c08d84000001')
```

Mongoid 3 with moped:

```
Moped::BSON::ObjectId.from_string('506144650ed4c08d84000001')
```

Mongoid 4 (moped) / Mongoid 5/6/7 (mongo):

```
BSON::ObjectId.from_string('506144650ed4c08d84000001')
```

Comment: This works for me oid = `BSON::ObjectId.from_string('506144650ed4c08d84000001')` but not with `Moped` on Mongoid 4.

Comment: `BSON::ObjectId.from_string('506144650ed4c08d84000001')` works for me on Rails 5 and Mongoid 7. Also referred to https://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongodb/bson-ruby/BSON/ObjectId

Comment: @CyberMew: waaaaat, mongoid 7? I'm not even on 6 yet. :/

Answer (score 0):

```
collection.delete_one({"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId(params['id'])})
```

This worked for me and it deleted the record from the database successfully

Answer (score 0):

There's a shorter way:

```
BSON::ObjectId("id_here")
```

but for your case it would be easier to simply map the objects to ids before the comparison:

```
if my_array_of_BSON_ObjectIds..map(&:to_s).include?(@my_id_as_a_string)
```