# Searching via ID not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to build search functionality. It was working fine till now.I need to add search via ID also .So I am implemented but it doesn't work with ID

When search with this ID - **591999b244e6c332b8ab9a36** or any of the user ID .It doesn't give me any result

Here is my code

```
User.any_of({"_id":  /.*#{params[:search]}.*/},{"first_name": /.*#{params[:search].downcase}.*/},{"email": /.*#{params[:search].downcase}.*/},{"phone_number": /.*#{params[:search]}.*/},{"country": /.*#{params[:search]}.*/})
```

Comment: Why are you including `.*` at the start and end of each regex? This is an unnecessary performance hit.

Comment: okay I will remove it but still it doesn't work for search via ID

Comment: Also, can you try to create a **minimal** example here? Does the following also yield no result? `User.any_of({"_id":  /#{params[:search]}/})`

Comment: yeah I have even tried that but that doesn't work for me

Comment: What is the database record that you expect to be returned? I don't see why you'd ever want to search for an `_id` by regex ... Does searching by direct value work? A quick google shows examples calling `ObjectId` on the string - does that work?

Comment: i.e. `User.any_of({"_id": ObjectId(params[:search]), ...})`

Comment: okay let me try this

Comment: Getting this error undefined method `ObjectId' for User:Class Did you mean? object_id....when searching via ID

Comment: Stop blindly copy+pasting things. You have the power of the internet literally at your finger-tips. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12578867/1954610

Comment: I have already tried that solution doesn't work for me.